# NetCat never ending http session

Tags: netcat

I'm trying to use `netcat` to server some `bash` command results via a web interface, that stays running. The page is dynamic and needs to be updated upon loading.

Just an example with what I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  { echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'; echo -e "Hello World"; } | 
  nc -k -l -p 8888
done
```

Unfortunately upon loading the page in a web browser, the page just hangs. If I go into CLI and kill the current connection loop, the page will instantly load.

This is happening on 2 servers but is running just fine on another so I'm finding it odd...

Comment: Drop the `-k` option.

Comment: I originally didn't have -k in the command but found that immediately when my browser connects, netcat stops listening on the port.  The issue is still there with or without -k.

Comment: Why should the port be kept open after the message has been sent? It works here as expected when the `-k` is dropped, no hangs or other issues.

Comment: Because it needs to be accessible more than once, for whatever reason netcat seems to act differently on this server than on another one so it stops listening without -k but continues listening with it.

Comment: Oddly, enough this appears to only be happening on debian 7u1. Ubuntu it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 7u1 installs netcat with netcat-traditional which appears to have it's own set of problems, my original issue being one of them.

Removed netcat-traditional by running
`apt-get remove netcat-traditional` and installing the proper one with `apt-get install netcat-openbsd` everything works as it should!